# Como obter retorno da quantidade de uma palavra existente dentro de um arquivo.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando obter como retorno a quantidade de palavras de baixo nível (palavrões) em um texto, utilizando como base um outro arquivo .txt contendo as palavras(palavrões). O código que fiz só me retorna 1 (uma) ocorrência, sendo que existem 3 (três). O que eu poderia fazer para melhorar?

```
def read_file():
    with open(r'C:\movie_quotes.txt') as file: # Abertura do arquivo a ser analisado. 
        contents = file.read()
    print(contents)
    file.close()
    check_file(contents)


def check_file(text_check):
    bad_words = open(r'C:\palavroes_bloqueio.txt') # Palavras a serem procuradas.
    contents = list(bad_words)
    # print(contents)
    for name in contents:
        if name in text_check:
            print('Bad words found.')
            print(text_check.count(name))
    bad_words.close()


read_file()
```

Comment: Se a palavra `foo` for um palavrão, `foobar` deverá ser contabilizado como uma ocorrência de `foo`?

Comment: Não, No caso eu queria pegar a palavra inteira. No caso foobar não entraria. Obrigado!

Comment: Mas este ponto abordado por você foi ótimo. Pois se acontecer de não ter espaço entre uma palavra e outra em algum ponto do texto. não retornaria. Certo?

Comment: É por ai! Só que estou utilizando um arquivo .txt com as palavras que quero procurar em outro arquivo .txt. Obrigado!

Comment: Mas é exatamente o mesmo problema, basta você ler o conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: Certo! Estou testando o código e logo darei um retorno. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o problema é que seu segundo arquivo tem uma palavra por linha, e aí quando vai procurar no texto por essa palavra, ele procura a palavra e a quebra de linha e não encontra.

Por exemplo, arquivo *palavroes_bloqueio.txt*:

```
foo
bar
```

Ao procurar no texto, ele vai procurar por *foo\n* e não somente por *foo*

O que você pode tentar é trocar esse trecho:

```
bad_words = open(r'C:\palavroes_bloqueio.txt') # Palavras a serem procuradas.
contents = list(bad_words)
```

Por esse trecho:

```
with open(r'C:\palavroes_bloqueio.txt') as bad_words:
    contents = bad_words.read()

# Divide as palavras usando o delimitador \n
contents = contents.split('\n')
```

Obs: O arquivo já é automaticamente fechado se você usar a diretiva `with open('..') as filename`, então não precisa chamar `filename.close()` em seguida

Comment: Vou fazer um teste com o que você me passou. Obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou! Foi exatamente o que eu estava precisava amigo. Você foi no ponto certo do problema! Muito Obrigado!!!